# How to stop sideloading a tablet only app on a handset in Android

Tags: android, screen-size

How can I stop the user from sideloading a tablet only application on a phone?

Comment: Can you give more details about your problem?

Comment: If I declare my app to be a tablet only app, google play will not show my app in the search results of a phone user. What happens if a phone user gets hold of my application .apk file and manually installs it on his phone? So my question was, how do I stop the user from manually installing an application on his device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no mechanisms in the core Android OS to disable the ability to install an application based on the manifest filtration data for features like screen size, these values are only used by Google Play to determine which apps to show on which device.  If a user somehow gets ahold of your APK through back channels, you cannot stop them from installing it.

However, after the application is installed, you can make use of technologies like the [License Verification Library (LVL)](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) to keep applications that have been improperly installed (i.e. not through Google Play) from being used.

Answer (score 0):

You want to declare the following in the manifest: ([source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html))

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="false"
                  android:largeScreens="false"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

Beyond that, just make sure the app is [licensed](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html).

Comment: supports-screens in the manifest xml is used by Google play and other services to restrict a phone-only user from seeing the application. However, this won't stop the user from installing the application on a phone. If you get hold of the .apk file you can literally install on any android device.

Comment: Yes. Licensing seems to be the only way to stop access.