# How to prevent apk sideloading

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-theme

I am an Android theme designer and I publish my theme apks on Google Play.

I'm finding a lot of users are basically just stealing my themes.  These themes do not allow support for license checking.  Many users are simply installing the theme, then making a copy and refunding and then simply reinstalling the copied apk.

This is a huge issue and what I'm wondering is if anyone knows a way to add code to ie: the manifest that would prevent the apk from being installed from unknown sources? It would be great to have it where it attempts to reinstall and then just fails.

Of course this will not 100% stop the thefts because they can likely adb push the app or decompile and remove the code but it will certainly stop a lot of it I believe.  Before you just had to worry for the most part about users with root to access the data partition.

Now there are several non root required file apps that can copy apks from data which allows easy access for theft.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13771343/656243

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Play has a licensing service that checks to make sure the user actually did pay for the app on Google Play, called App Licensing. The Google Play Licensing service is primarily intended for paid applications that wish to verify that the current user did in fact pay for the application on Google Play. Here is the documentation on how to implement it into your app; https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html

Comment: Unfortunately with things like themes a license is of no use since there is no user interface of the app. Even if there were this would not stop them from using the actual theme. It would only prevent them from using for a dashboard app wrapped around the actual theme. They would still be able to apply and use the theme itself since it would appear as a selectable option in the stock theme chooser app.

Comment: I guess I am not understanding your setup. Is there any way you can provide an example of your application setup?

Comment: Well i can try to be a bit more clear.  So basically you install the theme via google play like any normal app.  Immediately the system theme chooser app will recoignize and load the theme and make it available as a selection for a user to pick.  The system theme chooser app does not check nor can it check for a license.  So there is no way to prevent a user from being able to use a theme once they have the apk.  So they're just downloading from play, copying the apk, refunding and reinstalling it.  And the system theme app reads it right away so it is a free for all for theives.

Comment: Since a theme chooser isn't part of AOSP, you might have to take that up with whatever theme chooser application you are referring to. I know with things like Nova Launcher, if you refund an icon pack then it gets removed from Nova automatically.

Comment: Well it is LG's new theme engine implemented into 7.0 nougat for the V20, G5 and Stylo 2.   Still hoping someone may have some ideas of what to try.  I know the google dialer app for example has code to prevent installation on non nexus devices via a manifest edit.  Whether this is possible to do or sonething i have to accept remains to be seen.